# What is a word or expression to describe a person as entertainment to pass the time?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests

If someone is being used or employed as entertainment to help someone else pass their time at work, but only in this capacity, what word or expression can be used to describe this?

This other (working) person does not want to see or talk to the entertainer person outside of work.

I have heard "muse" but I don't think that is the right definition when I looked it up.

Comment: Does _eye candy_ fit? Maybe _distraction_.

Comment: *Upset?* As in, do you wish the person would want to spend time with you outside of work?  ;)

Comment: In several different contexts "prostitute" might fit.

Comment: @HotLicks, relevant username? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the answer right there in your question.

You're being employed as a *distraction*.

EDIT:  I am aware that *distraction* tends to have negative connotations.  That said, given that this person appears to only want you to be around at work to help him pass the time faster *at work*, and not in his social life, the entire situation appears negative (for you at least), and so it might be fitting, although Kris' answer "an amusement" is more negative towards you, whereas "distraction" might imply it is negative to this other guy.

Answer (score 0):

An object of entertainment?

Plaything, perhaps?

The OP's guess of 'muse' is close, though wrong: maybe, 'an amusement.'

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term to use is **work spouse**

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a reference for this term, or used it in a sentence as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you were just a **hobby**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `fool`, kings often had a fool on hand for entertainment. This person was considered a living joke, was treated poorly, and may even have been humiliated just to relieve a king's boredom.

> a professional jester, formerly kept by a person of royal or noble rank for amusement

- Ref: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fool

> Comic entertainer whose madness or imbecility, real or pretended, made him a source of amusement

- Ref: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fool